# Are questions about regulations on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Are regulations construed to be part of law on this site? Specifically, I have in mind a question [like the one I asked on politics SE](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/60746/does-the-uk-regulate-the-height-of-calf-hutches-relative-to-the-calves-living-in) about some UK farming/animal-welfare regulations.

I did a bit of searching here on law-meta, but I could not find a prior discussion on something like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Are questions about regulations on-topic?

Yes. The question "*is the height of the hutches regulated in the UK at least relative to the calves inside them?*" is intended to ascertain what, if anything, legislation says regarding animal control/care/protection. Therefore it is on topic regardless of whether the matter at issue is, or has ever been, regulated.

Even if a question does not refer to legislation at all, the matter could be on topic by virtue of contract, equity, or public policy.

Comment: Examples that are not legislation but on topic: Court Rules (they are not made by legislative), Trial Tactics.